# Why does django error "column posts_post.category_id does not exist" keep coming back up?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a django blog project which has the following core models:

> Models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):

    parentCategoryName = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, 
         null=True)
    parentCatSlug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    categoryName = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    categorySlug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):

        full_path = [self.categoryName]               
        k = self.parentCategoryName                          

        while k is not None:
            full_path.append(k.categoryName)
        k = k.parentCategoryName

        return ' -> '.join(full_path[::-1])

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.categorySlug = slugify(self.categoryName)
         self.parentCatSlug = slugify(self.parentCategoryName)
         super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=True)
    body = RichTextUploadingField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=True)
    titleSlug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    authorSlug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    editedimage = ProcessedImageField(upload_to="primary_images", 
        null=True,
                            processors = [Transpose()],
                            format="JPEG")
   show_in_posts = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.titleSlug = slugify(self.title)
        self.authorSlug = slugify(self.author)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

When I run makemigrations and migrate, all works fine initially, but then after a while, I get the error above. I've posted a question on this previously, and the solution was to drop the database and re-create it. This still works, but it happens frequently, so I keep having to drop and re-create. Can anyone help explain why this is seemingly sporadically happening?

> Traceback

```
File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (column posts_post.category_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "posts_post"."id", "posts_post"."title", "posts_post"...
                                                        ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/davidmellor/code/nomadpad/posts/views.py" in getPosts
  27.     return render(request, 'posts/getPosts.html', context)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  321.             if match:

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __bool__
  254.         self._fetch_all()

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1118.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  53.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  894.             raise original_exception

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  884.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  80.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /
Exception Value: column posts_post.category_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "posts_post"."id", "posts_post"."title", "posts_post"...
                                                        ^
```

> Migrations

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import ckeditor_uploader.fields
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
import django.utils.timezone
import imagekit.models.fields


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

initial = True

dependencies = [
    migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Category',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('parentCatSlug', models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)),
            ('categoryName', models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)),
            ('categorySlug', models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)),
            ('parentCategoryName', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='posts.Category')),
        ],
        options={
            'verbose_name_plural': 'categories',
        },
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Comment',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('title', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
            ('pub_date', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
            ('body', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
            ('approved_comment', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
            ('author', models.ForeignKey(default=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Post',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('title', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
            ('summary', models.CharField(default=True, max_length=500)),
            ('body', ckeditor_uploader.fields.RichTextUploadingField()),
            ('pub_date', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
            ('titleSlug', models.SlugField(blank=True)),
            ('authorSlug', models.SlugField(blank=True)),
            ('editedimage', imagekit.models.fields.ProcessedImageField(null=True, upload_to='primary_images')),
            ('show_in_posts', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
            ('author', models.ForeignKey(default=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ('category', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='posts.Category')),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Profile',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('bio', models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=500)),
            ('location', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)),
            ('birth_date', models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)),
            ('slug', models.SlugField(default='', unique=True)),
            ('profile_picture', models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='profile_images')),
            ('user', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='comment',
        name='post',
        field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='posts.Post'),
    ),
]
```

Comment: Please show the migrations files for that app.

Comment: As an aside, your `Category.__str__` might cause performance issues from huge numbers of queries in future. Try to avoid foreign key lookups in `__str__` (especially recursive ones!). You might find [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) useful if you want a tree of categories.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair, I was looking at mptt earlier actually. I'll give that a go once this is resolved :) Added migrations

Comment: Your migration file looks ok because it contains the `Post.category` field. If you run that migration on a new database it should create the `category_id` field, so I'm afraid I've got no idea why you would get `column posts_post.category_id does not exist` after a while.

Comment: No worries thank you anyway, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was deleting my migration files, I then went into the file structure of my mac, and cleared all pycache files too, which don't show up in my text editor. This worked, although my understanding of why is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from what I can see, it doesn't look like your Post model has a category_id field. I would have to see more of your code to understand why there is an SQL query trying to select on that field.

Can you maybe share the DB call that is generating the error?

Comment: Apologies @jcannell, semi-noob here, what is a DB 'call' ? Is it the view?

Comment: The `Post` model has `category` foreign key, so under the hood Django should create a `category_id` db field.